# VehicleObstacleShadowing configuration for Veins

Tags: veins

How should I configure VehicleObstacleShadowing in the config.xml file in VEINS? I could not find an example so asking here for experts to shed light on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are referring to whether it reads any parameters from the analoguemodel configuration (e.g., `config.xml`), it does not need any. You can double-check by looking at the [source code instantiating it](https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/veins-5.0/src/veins/modules/phy/PhyLayer80211p.cc#L240).

Comment: Yes, I figured that. Thank you :)